# Is there a relationship between the word amor (love) & mors (death)?

Tags: etymology

I recently read in a book that there is an etymological relationship between the Latin words amor & mort but no citation is given. Looking at an online etymological dictionary (Wiktionary) did not confirm this. Is anyone familiar with any sources claiming a relationship?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Presumably the basis of this made-up etymology is the fact that the words share a sequence of three letters. But *amor* comes from the root *am-* "love" plus the suffix *-or*, which is a common way to form abstract nouns. It does not contain an element *mor* that might be compared to *mors* (and even if it did, that wouldn't get us very far); the only thing shared between *am-* and *mort-*, the stem of *mors*, is the *m*. There is no relationship between the two words.